# Configuring 'deep' dependencies with Unity IoC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, inversion-of-control

Let's say I have the following classes and interfaces in my MVC 2 project:

Repositories:

IRepository1, IRepository2, IRepository3

```
public class ConcreteRepository1 : IRepository1
{
     public ConcreteRepository1()
     {
         ...
     }
     ...
}

public class ConcreteRepository2 : IRepository2
{
     public ConcreteRepository2()
     {
         ...
     }
     ...
}

public class ConcreteRepository3 : IRepository3
{
     public ConcreteRepository3()
     {
         ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Service classes:

```
public class Service1
{
    private IRepository1 repo1;
    private IRepository2 repo2;

    public Service1(IRepository1 repo1, IRepository2 repo2)
    {
        this.repo1 = repo1;
        this.repo2 = repo2;
    }
    ...
}
```

Controllers:

```
public class Controller1 : Controller
{
    private Service1 srv1;
    private Service2 srv2;

    public Controller1(Service1 srv1, Service2 srv2)
    {
        this.srv1 = srv1;
        this.srv2 = srv2;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have custom ControllerFactory and I know how to tie concrete repositories to interfaces:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepository1, ConcreteRepository1>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IRepository2, ConcreteRepository2>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IRepository3, ConcreteRepository3>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

The question is how should I register services' instances and controllers' types inside my custom ControllerFactory to make unity container resolve the whole hierarchy Controller->Service->Repository and avoid calling Resolve inside controllers or services?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have more than one Repository? Do you access different datasources? Just curious...

Comment: @Yves M.: I have one repository per aggregate root in my domain layer. I have one data source, but hypothetically this approach supports each aggregate root to be on it's own data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already registered `IRepository1-3`, so you can get `Service1` instance simply calling

```
container.Resolve<Service1>()
```

Calling `container.Resolve<Controller1>()` will automatically resolve dependencies and will create instance of type `Controller1`.

Sample:

```
public interface IRepository1 { }
public interface IRepository2 { }
public interface IRepository3 { }

public class ConcreteRepository1 : IRepository1 { }
public class ConcreteRepository2 : IRepository2 { }
public class ConcreteRepository3 : IRepository3 { }

public class Service1
{
    private IRepository1 repo1;
    private IRepository2 repo2;

    public Service1(IRepository1 repo1, IRepository2 repo2)
    {
        this.repo1 = repo1;
        this.repo2 = repo2;
    }
}

public class Service2
{
    private IRepository1 repo1;
    private IRepository2 repo2;

    public Service2(IRepository1 repo1, IRepository3 repo3)
    {
        this.repo1 = repo1;
        this.repo2 = repo2;
    }
}

public class Controller1
{
    private Service1 srv1;
    private Service2 srv2;

    public Controller1(Service1 srv1, Service2 srv2)
    {
        this.srv1 = srv1;
        this.srv2 = srv2;
    }
}
```

Resolving:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepository1, ConcreteRepository1>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository2, ConcreteRepository2>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository3, ConcreteRepository3>();

var controller = container.Resolve<Controller1>();
```

**EDIT**:

```
public interface IRepository { }
public class Repository : IRepository { }

public class Service
{
    //[InjectionConstructor]
    public Service()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parameterless constructor called");
    }

    public Service(IRepository repository)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contructor with IRepository called");
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
    var service = container.Resolve<Service>();
    container.RegisterType<Service>(new InjectionConstructor());
    var service2 = container.Resolve<Service>();
}
```

Output:

```
Contructor with IRepository called
Parameterless constructor called
```

So, when we haven't registered `Service` (in other words, it has default resolving behavior), Unity constructs `Service` using greediest constructor by default. When you specify `new InjectionConstructor()`, this tells Unity to use parameterless constructor. The same behavior can be received if you mark constructor (in this case `public Service()`) with `InjectionConstructorAttribute`.

Comment: I see, thanks. And I was trying to register all controllers' types with the code below and when I removed it everything worked: `var controllerTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
          where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
          select t;

   foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
   {
    container.RegisterType(t, new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
   }`

Comment: So it looks like in this case all services/controllers types get kind of autoregistered with Unity, right? Is there a way I can disable this "autoregistration" and manually register each type/instance one by one or all together?

Comment: @Intruder, Sure, you can, without setting any "disable autoresolving" option. What exception did you catch?

Comment: When I manually register controllers with code provided in my first comment to your answer I get "<ControllerName> does not have a constructor that takes the parameters ().  Source : Microsoft.Practices.Unity" exception

Comment: @Intruder, That is because you pass `new InjectionConstructor()` without parameters, therefore Unity tries to resolve `Controller` class using parameterless constructor, and as I see, your `Controller` constructor has 2 parameters. What is main purpose of register types by yourself?

Comment: The purpose is kind of illusion of better control over situation :) Also isn't there some overhead with autoregistering? And another reason is of course to learn what actually happens under the hood. So how should I use that InjectionConstructor in a proper way?

Comment: @Intruder, autoresolving is great feature of containers. As I see, you are using ASP.NET MVC. It has considered infrastructure to use IoC. Also, I've updated my answer with simple sample.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4035/discussion-between-intruder-and-kirill-polishchuk)

Answer (score 0):

surely just the following -

```
container.RegisterType<Service1>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

and the same for `Service2`. The IoC container will construct the objects for you